# Copying Selected file from OpenFileDialog c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to copy a file from OpenFileDialog to a file path
And I'm still a basic so it's hard for me. I google stuffs too but I dont understand that much.
Can someone please help me out

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Show the dialog and get result.
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            string newPath = @"C:\Users\" + un + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\NF";
            File.SetAttributes(newPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
            File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, newPath, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what problem are you facing ?

Comment: It says the target is a directory not a file thingy :3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument of [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx) is the name of the file in the new path.
You are passing a directory name.

Add this to your code before copying

```
string destFile = Path.Combine(newPath, Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName));
File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, destFile, true);
```

Apart from this I recommend to not build your paths using string concatenations. This could be easily a source of errors.  Use always the methods available in the [class Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string newPath = Path.Combine("C:\\Users",  un, "AppData\\Roaming\\NF");
```